# Why getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException in finding substring

Tags: c#

Length of `clines[i]` is `69`
I have initialized `index = 50`

Code:

```
string substr = clines[i].Substring(index, clines[i].Length);
```

Now I want substring from index `50` to `69`
But I am getting below exception

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location
>   within the string. Parameter name: length

why I am getting this exception?

Comment: `Substring` is not `(from, to)`. It's `(from, howmany)` Reading the actual documentation could have answered you, rather than creating this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error in your code is that `index` + `clines[i].Length` must not exceeds actual string's length which is `clines[i].Length` and that's why you're going to have the error for every non-zero `index`.

Try *dropping* the last argument (if you want to get the substring starting from the `index` and *up to the end*):

```
 string substr = clines[i].Substring(index);
```

**Edit:** A (wordy) alternative with *two* arguments is

```
 string substr = clines[i].Substring(index, clines[i].Length - index);
```

Please, notice that the last argument is the length of the *substring*, not of the original one.

Comment: string substr = clines[i].Substring(index); This worked. But I have a question in substring() we don't have to pass last index? Why?

Comment: @Surabhi Pandey: You can well put it as  `string substr = clines[i].Substring(index, clines[i].Length - index);` but why bother with the last argument when you have a sutable method's overload? Since .Net provides `Substrting(index)` method which means "starting from `index` and up to the end", why don't we use it?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for correcting. Removed my comment.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko-    Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the second argument represents the length of the segment you want to take, not the index to which you want the segment to extend to.

Also, if you want the right part of the string -- you can just leave off the second parameter.

```
clines[i].Substring(50, 19);
```

Comment: yeah I got it now. I am new to c# . Thanks.